# Русские символы после декодирования

Tags: javascript

Реализовал этот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623768/decrypting-aes-with-javascript-cryptojs-after-encrypting-with-php-mcrypt
Работает, но русские символы перестали отображаться. Вместо "Пример" получаем "Ïðèìåð". Онлайн декодеры говорят вот что: CP1252->CP1251 или ISO-8859-1 ->CP1251. Не получается отобразить русские символы. Сама страница в windows-1251.
кодируются некоторые значения в JSON. 
PHP:

```
*function encrypt($content)
{
$key = 'key_value';
$iv = 'iv_value';
$encrypted = base64_encode(
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
$key,
$content,
MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
$iv
)
);
return $encrypted;
}*
```

Для JS https://code.google.com/archive/p/js-mcrypt/

```
var Mdecrypt = function (data, key, iv)
{
return mcrypt.Decrypt(atob(data), iv, key, 'rijndael-128', 'cbc');
};
```

В итоге непонятные символы. Может можно их "перевести" на русский?

Comment: Покажите Ваш код

Comment: Как по мне - непохоже, что проблема в коде, нечему тут ломать кириллицу. Я бы рекомендовал проверять кодовые страницы самих исходников и шаблон страницы (там где head). Вопрос мне кажется закрыли может и не зря, но точно формулировка закрытия некорректна. Мне кажется, что автору стоит поискать условия воспроизведения бага - но пока я пожалуй за переоткрытие вопроса.